# RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800

Tags: python, random, scipy

I have an image where I pick a randow row in it and try to fit a Gaussian curve in that row. I am using **scipy.optimize curve_fit method** for fitting a Gaussian.

Picking of the randow rows are according to an array vector [10, 20, 40, 60, 100], meaning that in the first try I pick 10 randow rows (hence, 10 Gaussian fits) in that image, then, more rows are selected and so on.

Most of time, code is working, however, sometimes I get an error (especially, when the number of rows are large: around 60 or more), which says **optimal parameters are not found**.

I have found some similar posts in stackoverflow but still can not able to solve this problem. It seems like this problem appears quite often with **curve_fit method**.

Answer (score 6):

Laser beam, by any chance? ;-)

Anyway, the problem will probably be that the rows that get selected are "hard" to fit a Gaussian curve to by [scipy's curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) function. My first suggestion is to debug (using e.g. python's [logging](http://pymotw.com/2/logging/) module) to see if the error pops up only on specific rows.

My second suggestion is to change the **initial guess** for the curve_fit. From rows where curve-fitting is possible, you should be able to extract a few parameters. On other rows, the mean of the Gaussian is at approximately the same position and the aplitude will not vary as much either. A good initial guess will definitely help the curve fitting.

If you want to analyze the issue, I'd definitely do both: try to find rows for which the curve fitting fails after 800 iterations. Then see if the curve fitting works by changing the initial guess.

Comment: You can use signal.argrelmax to find local maxima, that are good candidates to centres of the gaussians

Comment: *Arghhh damn laser beams...!*